# Dim Light Problem

Tags: 13.04

I have a DELL laptop , which is can dim the light of the screen , by keyboard , but when i turn to dim the light , the system freeze and does not respond for any thing , could you help me ??

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072482&p=12356827#post12356827) is a massive hack from the Ubuntu forums, but perhaps the work-around will tide you over until there is a real fix.

> First I press Fn + Right arrow and then my keyboard backlight is
>   switched on but the keyboard is locked. So then I press the Fn + Esc
>   or the Fn + F1 keys which both put my laptop on sleep mode, then I
>   just switch on (awake) my laptop and the keyboard is unlocked with the
>   backlight working.I have no idea what's going on but it works. So it's
>   not ideal as if I pres the Fn+ Right arrow again (to adjust or switch
>   off the backlight) it locks the keyboard again but at least it allows
>   me to use the backlight function.